# Flex: arrayCollection inside another ArrayCollection?

Tags: apache-flex

can I create an ArrayCollection into another ArrayCollectionon in Flex ?

(or just an array.. or a list if I cannot)

thanks

Comment: you want to put an ArrayCollection inside another ArrayCollection ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is no reason why you couldn't do it.

```
        var array:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        var childArray:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        childArray.addItem("test");
        array.addItem(childArray);
```